# How to insert data into mysql server database using jdbc mysql driver through HTML and Servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, spring-jdbc

When I run the html file, fill the data, get the blank page and run the servlet file "http status 405-get method is not 
allowed by this url" error occurs.

Also the class not found exception error is the main error in my code 
that occurs from starting.
I'm been trying to solve this problem for the last 4-5 days but I couldn't find a solution.

Enter code here out from this problem.

I have added **servlet-api.jar** and **mysql-connector-java- 8.0.12.jar** files.

Please, solve my problem.

This is my `index.html`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="/InsertServlet">
     Username: <input type="text" name="username"/><br/><br/>
     Password: <input type="password" name="password"/><br/><br/>

     <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
     <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
     </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

This is my `InsertServlet.java` class

```
    package org.studyeasy.servlet;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.sql.*;
    import javax.servlet.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;


    public class InsertServlet extends HttpServlet {
        Connection con;
        Statement st;
        String user,pass;
     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
     HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

      try (PrintWriter out=response.getWriter()){
        user=request.getParameter("username");
        pass=request.getParameter("password");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection
      ("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase","root","rohini2722");
        st=con.createStatement();

        String query="insert into Login values('"+user+"','"+pass+"')";
        st.executeUpdate(query);

        System.out.println("Data Inserted Successfully");

     }
     catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }
    }
```

This is my `web.xml`

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
        version="2.5">
        <display-name>Login Page</display-name>
       <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
      <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>InsertServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>InsertServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.studyeasy.servlet.InsertServlet</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>InsertServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/InsertServlet</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

Comment: Could you update your post with the stack trace for the **ClassNotFoundException**.

Comment: @Rohini Gaikwad Did you checked answer ?

Comment: This is not tried but i will try right now

Comment: Where you put your jsp page ?

Comment: can you upload your project in github or gitlab ?